# how to close GTK window with C

Tags: c, gtk

i was doing a small project where i had a a fullscreen GUI (Glade, GTK and C) and needed to give the user a way to close the screen (obviously the window manager was not available due to the window being fullscreen).

problem rices when i attempt to compile this piece of code

```
//close sidebar1
 void on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked()
 {
    gtk_window_close (GtkWindow *window);
 }
```

i receive the following error

```
    /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c -g -O0 -Wall -pthread -pipe src/main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o main.o
src/main.c: In function 'on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked':
src/main.c:61:2: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'gtk_window_close'
  gtk_window_close (GtkWindow *window);
  ^
src/main.c:61:20: error: expected expression before 'GtkWindow'
  gtk_window_close (GtkWindow *window);
                    ^
makefile:30: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I tried to follow the documentation [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-close), but seem to have failed badly

Does anyone have any ideas?

PS.

here is the full main.c if someone is intrested. Its my first attempt at C with gtk, so dont be too harsh, Thank you (=

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *g_lbl_test;
GtkWidget *g_lbl_count;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "glade/window_main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    //pointers for the labels (...used in button press)
    g_lbl_test = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_test"));
    g_lbl_count = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_count"));

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    //gtk_window_fullscreen (GtkWindow *window);  //dont know how to use this, same with gtk_window_close
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

//button press (just a test to make sure the window didnt freeze)
void on_btn_count_clicked()
{
        static unsigned int count= 0;
        char str_count[30] = {0};

        gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_lbl_test), "Test success!");
        count++;
        sprintf(str_count, "%d", count);
        gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_lbl_count), str_count);
}

//sidebar1
void on_sidebar_1_clicked()
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "glade/window_main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_sidebar1"));

    gtk_widget_show(window); 
}
//close sidebar1
 void on_window_sidebar1_back_clicked()
 {
    gtk_window_close (GtkWindow *window);
 }


// called on closing window
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

Comment: What? Why are you writing a *declaration* here? How about **calling** this function with an actual `GtkWindow *` pointer pointing to your window?

Comment: gtk_window_close (&window) maybe ? or gtk_window_close (window) ?

Comment: as in gtk_window_close (GtkWindow *window_sidebar1);  //window_sidebar1 is the ID for my window

Comment: This is not valid C. In the function call you mustn't specify types but only provide the values.

Comment: On the other hand your function signature look way too empty to be correct. To which signal is that function connected?

Comment: on second thought, you are all going way over my head. Maybe i should hit the schoolbench again. Thank you all for help... and sorry for wasting your time )=

Comment: edited the main topic, if someone wants to take it and attempt to compile it. I was running (and compiling) it on a armv7 (armhf) debian xfce system using GCC as my compiler

Comment: You have two issues. First, you are not familiar enough with C programming. So take several days or weeks to learn more abnout C programming. Then, you need to spend a few days or weeks to learn more about GTK. In both cases we don't have time (and space) to teach all this, so I voted for close as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should call

```
 gtk_close_window(window);
```

But that `window` should come from somewhere.

(you may use a Gtk closure with a connection, or a callback with a client data, etc. or store somehow that `window` in a global variable, etc...)

Read more about C programming, then read a bit about [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) and [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), then read more about [GTK](http://gtk.org/), and the [signal](http://ile:///usr/share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Signals.html) mechanism of Gobject.

<sup>(your code shows a lot of confusion; I suggest to read the [Getting started with GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) chapter after having read a good C programming book; BTW, I suggest to first write something which is *not* fullscreen, and only later improve it)</sup>

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling, that is compile with 
 `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (and other arguments, perhaps using `$(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)` and also `$(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)` for linking).

Comment: thanks for the help, but i think i just need to hit some basic tutorials to get the hang of C again. Serious case of PEBCAS. Should i delete the post or just leave it here as "unsolved"?

Comment: What does PEBCAS mean?

Comment: problem exists between chair and screen, if i recall correctly

Comment: I think you mean [PEBKAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error); BTW for most sitting positions your *brain* is not between chair & screen :-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you are even more off. PEBKAS ... "Between Keyboard and Screen" does not make any sense unless you sit on your desktop and type behind your back. :) What you mean is **PEBKAC**: Between Keyboard and Chair.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Basile meant "between keyboard and sofa", clearly `:-)`

Comment: The command suggested by Answerer does not match GTK3.  Did you mean ``gtk_window_close``?  See: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-close

Answer (score 0):

Attention! This does not follow any industrial standards and there are multiple flaws in this. I don't make any money or fame out of this so my only requirement is that it works. Take this into consideration when reading this!

I made edits to my code with what I learned and this seems to work:

```
void on_sidebar_1_clicked(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "glade/window_sidebar1.glade", NULL);  //a whole own file for the second window

    secondWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_sidebar1")); //secondWindow is defined at the start of main.c like this: "GtkWidget *secondWindow = NULL;" so that both callbacks can use it.
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);


    gtk_widget_show(secondWindow);
    gtk_main();

}


void on_sidebar1_back_clicked()
 {
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(secondWindow)); //here we call the widget to be closed instead of the window. Seems to work a lot better than the gtk_window_close, dunno why.
 }
```

This code was written fast (and furious) so it's a little crude. I made some changes to my glade files as well, if someone needs a reference to those, please ask. As far as I care, this was the answer for my question. Also, I would recommend learning C and GTK (like Basile Starynkevitch said) before you start doing this kind of stuff, I didn't have the time nor motivation to do so.

Comment: Sorry but this code makes no sense either.  You don't pass `argc` and `argv` to a callback, not call `gtk_init` in a callback. This is supposed to be done in your `main` function. Furthermore, no GTK callbacks take 0 arguments, so the signature for `on_sidebar1_back_clicked` is most certainly wrong too.

Comment: hey, it certainly is stupid, but it works. DO NOT USE THIS FOR ANY INDUSTRIAL STANDARD, should probably be added. Just downvote it if its  not to your liking (=. Ill see if i can make it work without the init, but i swear i had some problems without them. could be just some semicolon that i missed when not having them.

Comment: libforce, thanks for the tip! it works just fine without the init when creating new windows., if not better (a little faster, nothing noticeable though)

Comment: Passing less arguments or brutal force type arguments in callbacks is the exact magic of the gtk c level API. It's used as design. It can save some typing. als gtk_init is not used anymore. Other then this it IS THE STANDARD WAY  way to force the close of a window. Calling close on a window is just a suggestion and result in a close request callback. But Destroying will always succeed even if there is for example a modal dialog visible. Oh and in Gtk4 it should now be "gtk_window_destroy" instead of "gtk_widget_destroy"